# How do I make menu item clickable and display a toast after clicked android?

Tags: java, android

Hello I having a problem trying to get eclipse to recognized my menu icon. I want to have the icon appear in the action bar and when clicked, I want to display a toast.The problem is that my save icon is not being recognized in eclipse.  Here is my code :

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.profilemenu, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
        case android.R.id.save:
            save cannot be resolved or is not a field

        }

        return false;
    }
```

The menu :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/save" android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/save_str" android:icon="@drawable/content_save" />
</menu>
```

Comment: use  `R.id.save` instead of `android.R.id.save` for Save menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the incorrect identifier within the switch statement, you should use just `R.id.Save`, like so:

```
switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.home:
        finish();
    case R.id.save:
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Toast message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

Using the `android` identifier means you are trying to find a resource built into the android sdk which doesn't exist.

Comment: You should mark this as the answer if it fixes your issues. :)

Comment: Yeah I would of done it earlier, but it told to wait a few minutes.